# Adding a preferences window to a Mac App

Tags: objective-c, macos, window, preferences

Ok so i've made and app and i want to add a preferences window to my app which is accessible from the menu bar.

Can anyone provide me with a tutorial or guide on how to do this, thanks, Sami.

Comment: Do you mean like a window from within the app or a section under System Preferences?

Comment: A window from within the app, where i can add sliders and color wells.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an article from Apple on [building a preferences pane using Cocoa Bindings](http://developer.apple.com/cocoa/cocoabindings.html)

Archive link:  http://web.archive.org/web/20120104093705/http://developer.apple.com/cocoa/cocoabindings.html